# JakeWhartons View pager indicator does not display dots

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-library

I am trying to implement the view pager indicator. This is the code in my onCreate method. I have followed the instructions on [this](https://github.com/JakeWharton/Android-ViewPagerIndicator) page to implement the library and yet nothing is being displayed as I flip through the pages.

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.item_view_tablet);

        Bitmap backgroundPic = mainPicBitmap("image_uri_from_db");
        mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

        mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        Drawable backgroundDrawable = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(),backgroundPic);
        mViewPager.setBackground(backgroundDrawable);
        mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);

        CirclePageIndicator titleIndicator = (CirclePageIndicator) findViewById(R.id.indicator);
        titleIndicator.setViewPager(mViewPager);

        db.close();
    }
```

This part `CirclePageIndicator titleIndicator = (CirclePageIndicator) findViewById(R.id.indicator);
            titleIndicator.setViewPager(mViewPager);` is supposed to make it work, but nothing displays. I checked the sample application and it is used the same way. What am I doing wrong? Any suggestions appreciated

My layout file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="400sp"
    android:orientation="vertical" xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/co.za.datasolve.acollect">

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".ViewCategoryTabletActivity" >
    </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

    <com.viewpagerindicator.CirclePageIndicator
        android:id="@+id/indicator"
        android:padding="10dip"
        android:layout_height="20sp"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Can you post the layout file?

Comment: Sure, there it is @Luksprog

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You use a vertical `LinearLayout` and you've set the height of the `ViewPager`(the first child of the `LinearLayout`) to `match_parent` which will make it take the whole height of the parent pushing the indicator outside. Try something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="400sp"
    android:orientation="vertical" xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/co.za.datasolve.acollect">

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        tools:context=".ViewCategoryTabletActivity" >
    </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

    <com.viewpagerindicator.CirclePageIndicator
        android:id="@+id/indicator"
        android:padding="10dip"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Brilliant, thanks a million! I was scratching my head with a passion